# HTML5 Javascript, Updating a text using arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

Dont mind my code, it is probably very terrible in the eyes of professionals aha but anyway
i am coding a game where the user has to answer a question with 3 options, the question, the 3 answers are all set in arrays [1] to [10]. My problem is that when the question is asked, the question wont update on the website.

```
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var Question = new Array(10);
    var Answer1 = new Array(10);
    var Answer2 = new Array(10);
    var Answer3 = new Array(10);
    var i = 1;

   (example of one question)
    Question[1] = "What time is it?";
    Answer1[1] = "1.I dont know";
    Answer2[1] = "2.Party Time";
    Answer3[1] = "3.None of your business";
   </script>

   (my function that writes the questions/answers)
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayQuestions() {
            document.write(Question[i].toString());

            document.write("\n <br>" + Answer1[i].toString());

            document.write("\n <br>" + Answer2[i].toString());

            document.write("\n <br>" + Answer3[i].toString());   
    }
    </script>
    </head>


 <body>  

  <div>My Question Game!</div>
    <div id="Question"><script type="text/javascript">displayQuestions();</script></div>

    <button onclick="answerGet()">Answer</button> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
     function answerGet()
        {
        var answer = 0;    
        answer = parseInt(prompt("Please enter your answer (1 - 3) "));
        if (answer < 4 && answer > 0) {

          } else if (isNaN(answer)) {
            parseInt(prompt("It is not a number. Please enter a number from 1 to 3", ""));

         } else {
         parseInt(prompt("Your number (" + answer + ") is above 3. Please enter a number from 1                to 3")); 

         if ((answer() === CorrectAnswer[i])) {
                score = score + 50;
            } 
            i = i + 1;
            alert(i);
            Question = Question[i];
            Answer1 = Answer1[i];
            Answer2 = Answer2[i];
            Answer3 = Answer3[i];
            CorrectAnswer = Correctanswer[i];
        }
```

Comment: Please, put a title that describes your problem. This title doesn't say anything...

Comment: What exactly do you expect to update?

Comment: Don't use document.write, use element.innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

To make your program a bit more slick, you should use jquery.

Sans that to fix your immediate problem, try calling your displayQuestions function after the correct answer is given, like the following:

```
        Answer1 = Answer1[i];
        Answer2 = Answer2[i];
        Answer3 = Answer3[i];
        CorrectAnswer = Correctanswer[i];
        displayQuestions();
```

Comment: As an additional note, it will increment and it will change the question every time you click "Answer" and call answerGet.  I would recommend getting something like Chrome and click on Tools->Developer Tools, then step through your program using the Javascript debugger, you'll be able to clearly see where your logic path is amiss and you'll also be able to see what variables are set and where they are set at.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't that bad. Here is how you can update the questions:

In your `answerGet()` function, add the following to the `if ((answer() === CorrectAnswer[i]))` block

```
var question = document.getElementById('question');
question.innerHTML = displayQuestions();
```

This will get the text from `displayQuestions()` and put it inside the question div. But there is still a problem, the `displayQuestions()` function actually prints to the screen. We want it to return text instead, like this:

```
function displayQuestions() {
    var text = Question[i].toString();
    text += "\n <br>" + Answer1[i].toString())
    text += "\n <br>" + Answer2[i].toString();
    text += "\n <br>" + Answer3[i].toString(); 
    return text;  
}
```

Now one final problem: the code that prints the first question is now wrong because the `displayQuestions()` function doesn't print anything, just returns the text. Lets fix that:

```
<div id="Question"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(displayQuestions());</script><div>
```

That should do it. Let me know if you have any trouble implementing that.